# how to change marker angle in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I want show one marker with normal angle 90 degrees(it is default of openlayers) and other marker with 120 degrees in openlayers. To differentiate with the normal ones.
how can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate a feature.  Here's an example.

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/rotate-features.html

Comment: but i want to the marker to bend little bit, not exactly rotating.. so how can i achieve this.

Comment: The example has animated rotation.  That's just "cute".  But the meat is there in the .rotate() function call.  You original question stated you wanted to rotate by 120 deg.  The rotate() function is your perfect answer.  Unless...it's something else you're looking for and you might need to restate your question.

Comment: yes i have to rotate the marker with some angle other than regular one. will try that thanks..